# XQuery To Select Related Node

Tags: xquery, xquery-sql

Given the below XML, what would be the proper SQL XQuery to retrieve the SubscriberStatus where the SubscriberID is empty? Given the XML is stored in a column with the XML datatype.

`<ObjectEntry>
            <Key>Key1</Key>
            <DicValue>
                <ObjectEntry>
                    <Key>SubscriberStatus</Key>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Active</Value>
                    <DicValue />
                </ObjectEntry>
                <ObjectEntry>
                    <Key>SubscriberID</Key>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                    <DicValue />
                </ObjectEntry>
            </DicValue>
        </ObjectEntry>`

Comment: There is no such thing like SQL XQuery. There simply are relational databases which also support XQuery. In this context, there is no difference whether you execute the XQuery in a relational database or somewhere else.

Comment: -1 for not showing an attempt to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions! Unfortunately they didn't do what I was asking, but did help me get the right syntax. Here's a solution that works.

`select Request.query('//ObjectEntry/DicValue/ObjectEntry[Key = "SubscriberStatus"]/Value') as SubscriberStatus
from RequestLog
where
Request.exist('//ObjectEntry/DicValue[ObjectEntry[Key = "SubscriberID" and Value = ""]]') = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

If $node holds your xml fragment then

> $node//ObjectEntry[DicValue/ObjectEntry[Key eq "SubscriberStatus"] and DicValue/ObjectEntry[Key eq "SubscriberID"][Value ne ""]]

will give you back the ObjectEntry parent for the non empty SubscriberIDs

Answer (score 1):

This is a simply XPath expression, there is no need for true XQuery. XPath is a subset of XQuery. Given that you want the `<Value/>` element of the SubscriberStatus you can get it like the following:

```
//ObjectEntry/DicValue[ObjectEntry[Key = "SubscriberID"]/Value = ""]/ObjectEntry[Key = "SubscriberStatus"]/Value
```

This fetches all ObjectEntries which do have an empty SubscriberID and then navigates to the SubscriberStatus. If you just want the actual string, you cann append `/string()`